# When using Qt in VS2008, IntelliSense does not work properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt

I use Qt 4.4.2 in Visual Studio 2008.

When I am writing code, IntelliSense seems to die - it does not show any methods or data members in Qt objects such as QPushButton, does not see the QObject::connect static method, etc.

Is it a typical situation or did I do something wrong while installing the library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely non-standard extensions like `public slots:` etc.

There's already a FAQ at the Qt site: [Intellisense does not work for my Qt application. What's wrong?](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/intellisense_does_not_work_for_my_qt_application._whats_wrong)

Comment: it`s OK now - I used Qt->Update IntelliSense

Comment: of course, Project->Update Intellisense - I mixed up menu buttons:)

Comment: @chester89: no such menu here in VS2008 (not in Qt, nor in Project)!

Comment: @Cornelius: This link works=> http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/intellisense_does_not_work_for_my_qt_application._whats_wrong

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Intellisense about the QT include directories. This can be found by going to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories . Add them to the *Show Directories for: Include Files* list on the right. I don't know if the QT installation does this by default or not.

Also, make sure that your VS Project files have the QT include directories as part of the *Additional Include Directories* under C/C++ General settings. (Although you probably have this already if you can successfully compile).

Comment: You mean to the shown directories? Anyway, it doesn't solve the problem. Btw. this is the "Path to use when searching for include files while building a VC++ project." - it doesn't seem to be related to IntelliSense. Also, other libraries work perfectly fine without having their include directories listed here.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to VisualAssist. It is the must anyway.

Comment: and my project will grow faster). visual assist is a little bit more powerful than Intellisense itself, the difference is just VA is a plugin for VS:)

Comment: see Visual Assist / Qt tips at http://blog.wholetomato.com/2008/11/20/using-qt-44-with-visual-assist-x/

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was solved by deleting the solution's .ncb file, then rebuilding to regenerate it.  After that the intellisense worked.