# Cannot find include file QtCore?

Tags: c++, qt4, qthread

I'm writing a multithreaded program in C++, and plan to use `QThread`. Problem is when I try to `#include <QtCore>`... I get an error... `Cannot find include file QtCore.`

What gives?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have the include directories point to root include directory of Qt, so try:

```
#include <QtCore/QtCore>
```

... or... you don't have the include directories refering to Qt in your compiler command line.

Comment: Check the compiler settings. I don't know what compiler do you use. If gcc, check for -I option for Qt include directory. If Visual Studio, check the include directories settings in your project or environment.

Comment: Messing around with the netbeans project settings. I've found two options. Creating a project with a "Qt Static Library" and creating a project with "Qt Dynamic Library". Any idea on what the difference is?

Comment: It has nothing to do with include headers. It is about how to use qt (linked in your binary, or as dynamic library - DLL or so).

Answer (score 3):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675005/when-using-qt-in-vs2008-intellisense-does-not-work-properly) has an answer which worked for me when Visual Studio did not recognize #include statements in my Qt project. While compiling and building worked in my case, the IDE would indicate that the #include line was incorrect and show a message 'Cannot find include file XXX'.

The question linked to above points to a nokia page about [intellisense and QT](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/intellisense_does_not_work_for_my_qt_application._whats_wrong) which indicates that Visual Studio should be launched from the "Qt x.xx for Desktop (MSVC 20xx)" command prompt included with the binary distribution of QT. After launching Visual Studio from the QT command prompt my problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your .pro file is configured incorrectly.

Your error's source is the compiler, which is fed the wrong include directories - this is why QtCore can't be found.

This can happen if you don't use qmake (and a plain Makefile instead), CMake and have it configured incorrectly, etc., etc. To be honest, it can have a lot of reasons.

Can you post the contents of your .pro-file or Makefile? And tell us a bit more about more about *how* you actually start compilation?

Comment: The problem seems to have fixed itself (as if by magic). So no more help is needed. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar Problem was searching and reinstalling after i found out that i had to install the windows 10 sdk configure debugger on qt creator most important when i started the qtwidget project i used at the beginning the windows .Net Framework and then the qt widget

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).